# Python (3.2.3) If Or Statement Syntax Error

Tags: python, syntax, if-statement, conditional-statements

Thanks for reading this. I'm trying to do [this lab from programarcadegames.com](http://programarcadegames.com/index.php?chapter=lab_create_a_quiz#section_24) where you have to write a quiz. I finished my first question and got a syntax error. Here's the code:

```
print ("This is a quiz.")
x=0
questionOne=input("First question! How many fingers does a human have? "
if questionOne == "10" or questionOne.lower() == "ten":
                   print ("Correct! Good job!")
                   x+=1
else:
                   print ("Not quite... try the next one!")
print ("You got the following amount of questions right:",x)
```

When I go to run it, I get a syntax error and the Python shell editor window highlights the colon at the end of line four. Removing the colon causes it to highlight print on the next line. I've also tried removing the or statement and just making line four:

```
 if questionOne == "10":
```

for the sake of troubleshooting, but I ended up with the same error and red colon. Any ideas? Criticisms? Mocking comments? Thanks again for reading.

**EDIT:**
It wasn't the `.lowercase()` thing, fixed that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are missing a closing parenthesis on the previous line (the line with `input`).

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Code runs perfectly now.

Comment: @user1586423 If this solved your problem you should consider [accepting this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235). It'll reward both parties with some points and marks this problem as solved. This is SO's "thank you" mechanism :)